# How to switch from docker.io to quay.io?

Tags: linux, docker, quay.io

I need help how to switch from image registry server from docker.io to quay.io.
My cases is I pull centos image from hub.docker.com and I want to push it to quay.io.
I have login to my quay.io but when I try to push to quay like this shell that was not working.
Here are my step to switch to quay.io:

1. Create quay repository MYUSERNAME/centos
2. Logout from docker.io

```sh
# docker logout docker.io
```

3. Login to quay.io

```sh
# docker login quay.io
```

4. I fill the credential
5. I create new tag

```sh
# docker tag IMAGEID MYUSERNAME/centos:7
```

6. I push my image to quay

```sh
# docker push MYUSERNAME/centos:7
```

Here is output I got for the last shell command:

```sh
The push refers to repository [docker.io/MYUSERNAME/centos]
2653d992f4ef: Preparing 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I can see that registry image server still pointed to docker.io.

How to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: `docker tag IMAGEID quay.io/MYUSERNAME/centos:7` and `docker push quay.io/....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In super short, the tag is in format `site/something/name:tag` where:

- if `site` is missing, it is assumed to be `docker.io` (can't be changed)
- if `something` is missing, it is assumed to be `library`.
- if `:tag` is missing, it is assumed to be latest.

So for example `docker pull alpine` is the same as `docker pull docker.io/library/alpine:latest`.

If you want to use a repository with different address, you *have to* explicitly give its name when tagging:

```
docker tag IMAGEID quay.io/MYUSERNAME/centos:7
docker push quay.io/MYUSERNAME/centos:7
```

Comment: The test cases for this are in TestParseRepositoryInfo in distribution/reference//normalize_test.go: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adistribution/reference%20TestParseRepositoryInfo&type=code

The terminology in the tests is "RemoteName, FamiliarName, FullName, AmbiguousName, Domain".